# An Excel Transpose between 2 specific symbols

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I'm trying to organize catalog records exported from a very outdated program my library is using to get it ready to import into the new catalog. The records come out like this:

```
~#[K11

title[Yada Yada

date[19xx

Entry body text

Entry body text

Volume:1

Location: Outer Mongolia

]
```

And I'd like them to look like this all on one line transposed:

```
~#[K11 title[Yada Yada date[19xx Entry body text Entry body text Volume:1 Location: Outer Mongolia ]
```

The records may or may not have all fields, but they all start with '#[' and they all end with ']'. Since these are the only times these symbols show up I was trying to write a macro that would go down column A look for those symbols, and transpose everything between them. But I'm not good enough, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I am starting from code as answered so nicely by @Excellll in another post and this is where I am so far:

```
Dim n As Long
n =  30000
For i = 1 To n Step 5
    Range("A1:A5").Offset(i - 1, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B10").Offset((i - 1) / 5 + 1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
Next I
```

However, each entry is not 5 lines long so I can't use `Step 5`, also my data is not contiguous so I can't use `COUNTA`.

Any suggestions for a step of variable size between the two specific characters?

Comment: You have the right idea, you will need a macro to loop through all the data and reformat it but if you don't have anything to start with, you are kinda just asking someone to do it all for you.

Comment: I have how to transpose the data when I manually selected it:     
`code`
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub                                                                                                              `code`                                                                                                                   Now I'm working on how to define the selection as everything between '#[.....]' .

Comment: What is the format of your data? If it's .csv then I'd consider to format the data in another tool (e.g. Notepad++) using regex. That's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The below macro transforms the input data into the format you’ve specified. Hopefully the remaining records of your dataset will have similar structure else there’s of course room for modifications.
I wasn't quite sure about the `~` sign as it appears in the input but not in your further description. This can be addressed by modifying the `startString` variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub transpose()
Dim i As Long
Dim noOfRows As Long
Dim bc As String 'blank cell replacement
Dim startString As String
Dim endString As String
Dim record As String
Dim j As Long 'where to print record - row number
Const c As Long = 3 'where to print record - column number
Dim sheetname As String
Dim currentCellValue As String
Dim previousCellValue As String 'it is used to ignore multiple consecutive empty cells

startString = "~#["
endString = "]"
bc = " "
j = 1
sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

'number of rows used in s/s including blanks in between
For i = Worksheets(sheetname).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
noOfRows = i

'loop through all rows
For i = 1 To noOfRows
    currentCellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value
    'check if startsWith
    If InStr(Trim(currentCellValue), startString) = 1 Then
        record = currentCellValue
    'check if endsWith
    ElseIf Len(Trim(currentCellValue)) > 0 And Len(Trim(currentCellValue)) = InStrRev(Trim(currentCellValue), endString) Then
        record = record + currentCellValue
        'prints output records to the worksheet
        Cells(j, c).Value = record
        j = j + 1
        Debug.Print record
    ElseIf Len(Trim(currentCellValue)) = 0 And Len(Trim(previousCellValue)) > 0 Then
        record = record + bc
    'non blank cells which are between start and end strings
    ElseIf Len(Trim(currentCellValue)) > 0 Then
        record = record + currentCellValue
    End If
    previousCellValue = currentCellValue
Next i
End Sub
```